# Llamar clase dentro de otra en PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo esta clase que reproduce una canción por medio de *MediaPlayer*. Esto está funcionando bien. Ahora quiero implementar controles de reproducción en el área de las notificaciones, pero estoy teniendo problemas para llamar la clase que tengo dentro de **NotificationReturnSlot** donde agarro la acción correspondiente de cada botón.

Traté de poner la clase interna en otro archivo pero entonces no podía llamar los métodos de la clase `AudioInterface`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? o ¿Cómo podría hacerlo funcionar?

Aclaro que esto es una `Interface` llamada desde un *WebView*, la cual crea los controles de *Play* y pausa en la barra de notificaciones.

```
public class AudioInterface {
        private NotificationManager nManager;
        private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
        private RemoteViews remoteView;

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Context mContext;

    AudioInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    //Play an audio file from the webpage
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playAudio(String aud) { //String aud - file name passed
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //String url = aud;
        String url = "http://mysite.com/file.mp3";

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_image)
                .setOngoing(true);

        remoteView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.notificationview);

        //set the button listeners
        setListeners(remoteView);
        nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

        nManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
    }

    public void play(){
        this.mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause(){
        this.mPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
        //listener 1
        Intent playMP = new Intent(mContext,NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        playMP.putExtra("DO", "play");
        PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, playMP, 0);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn1, btn1);

        //listener 2
        Intent pauseMP = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        pauseMP.putExtra("DO", "pause");
        PendingIntent btn2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 1, pauseMP, 0);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn2, btn2);
    }

    public void notificationCancel() {
        nManager.cancel(2);
    }

    public class NotificationReturnSlot extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");

            if (action.equals("play")) {
                Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "play");

                Toast.makeText(this, "playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                play();

            } else if (action.equals("pause")) {
                //Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "stopNotification");
                Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "pause");

                Toast.makeText(this, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pause();
            }
            //finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo sufri el mismo problema, lo solucione con un **Broadcast**, primero creas los ACTION, se pueden ver en el package de tu Mainactivity, intentfilters ,los registers y les dices a los pending que manden eso a Broadcast

```
  public static String NEXT_ACTION="com.example.a7860k.reproductor.action.next";
  public static String PLAY_ACTION="com.example.a7860k.reproductor.action.play";
  private IntentFilter previus;
  private IntentFilter play;
  BroadcastReceiver receiver;

        Intent playMP = new Intent(PLAY_ACTION);
        playMP.putExtra("DO", "play");
        PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, playMP, 0);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn1, btn1);

        //listener 2
        Intent pauseMP = new Intent(NEXT_ACTION);
        pauseMP.putExtra("DO", "pause");
        PendingIntent btn2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1, pauseMP, 0);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn2, btn2);
```

Despues creas instancias a los filters y broadcast

```
play=new IntentFilter();
next=new IntentFilter();    
play.addAction(PLAY_ACTION);
next.addAction(NEXT_ACTION);
receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                if(intent.getAction().equalsPREV_ACTION)){
                                    actionPreviusSong();
                                }

                                if(intent.getAction().equals(PLAY_ACTION)){
                                   actionPlaySong();
                                }

                                if(intent.getAction().equals(NEXT_ACTION)){
                                   actionNextSong();
                                }
                            }
                        };
```

Y por ultimo los registras

```
 registerReceiver(receiver,play);
 registerReceiver(receiver,previus);
```

Este es un ejemplo que extraje de mi codigo obviamente abra discrepancia, trate de acomodarlo al tuyo para que sea mas sencillo.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo bastante. Con algunas modificaciones lo logre hacer andar!